# Mouse calibration in Sway

Tags: arch-linux, mouse, input-method, sway

I am using Wayland Sway in Arch and my pointer is not moving far enough across the screen for a given mouse movement. I assume that I need to change the calibration matrix for the mouse, however, there does not seem to be any documentation in Sway on how to do this. The man page just says that the calibration_matrix is 6 space-separated floating point values without further explaining how to set those values.

How can change the calibration for the mouse, in other words, the distance the pointer moves for a given unit of mouse travel?

Answer (score 1):

In sway's `libinput.c` the matrix is passed on to [`libinput_device_config_calibration_set_matrix()`](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/api/group__config.html#ga09a798f58cc601edd2797780096e9804).